# retrieving Apache log files from AWS Beanstalk

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, access-log

I know that Beanstalk's Snapshot Logs can give you a recent overview of the `httpd/access_log` files from among the EC2 instances under the ELB for that environment. But does anyone know a good way to get *all* the logs?

It's a production environment, so I want to do the processing elsewhere. But I don't want to (for obvious reasons) configure root sftp and go around collecting the files manually.

I think I had read something about configuring logging to S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Configuration" tab for an Environment, under "Software Configuration", there is a checkbox for enabling log file rotation to S3. These are stored in an S3 bucket used specifically for Elastic Beanstalk.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can feed your current logs to [aws cloudwatch logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html).

AWS cloudwatch logs will centralise all logs of your infrastructure with a neat solution to search an process them as well as creating metrix and alarm based on your logs.

I have a guide on how to [Store aws beanstalk symfony and apache logs in cloudwatch logs](http://www.albertsola.pro/store-aws-beanstalk-symfony-and-apache-logs-in-cloudwatch-logs/). This will help you to get up and running fast, and then you can tweak it.